# how to show error message when there only one item in jQuery Sortable and disable the dragging

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I Would like to show user an error  message when he/she tries to drag an item from list containing only one item.

I am able to disbale dragging option from the list when there is only one item using below code but i would like user to be informed as well by showing some messgage.

```
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3" ).sortable({
connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
 cancel: "li:only-child"
}).disableSelection();
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue using below code.

```
$(""#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3" ").on("sortremove", function(event, ui) {
    var $list = $(this);

    if ($list.children().length < 1) {
    alert("There should be at leat one item in the list");
        $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
    }
});
```